# Query records of 7/14/21/28... days ago in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table of users where I'm storing the registration date as UNIX timestamp. I would select all the users registered 7/14/21/28/... days ago. So if I have a situation like this (I'm not using unix timestamp in the example just to be more clear):

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
| ID | username   | registration_date             |
+----+------------+-------------------------------+
| 1  | user1      | 11-02-2014                    |
| 2  | user2      | 4-02-2014                     |
| 3  | user3      | 28-01-2014                    |
| 4  | user4      | 27-01-2014                    |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

The query should return the user #2, #3 but not the number #4 because he signup 15 days ago and 15 is not multiple of 7.

A spaghetti solution could be to write thousand of WHERE statement to select my records but I hope someone will help me finding a better one.

Comment: So you're interested in results where the number of days difference between then and now is equal to modulus 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE DATEDIFF(registration_date, NOW()) % 7 = 0
```

Check here datediff and mod operator

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod

Comment: Thanks for linking the documentation. Since my "registration_date" is a UNIX timestamp your query doesn't work. But looking at the documentation I found "FROM_UNIXTIME" and this is the solution for my question:

`SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE DATEDIFF( FROM_UNIXTIME( registration_date ) , NOW( ) ) %7 =0`

Comment: Yes FROM_UNIXTIME function does the conversion good catch :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here,

```
The DATEDIFF() function returns the time between two dates.
```

SQL FORMAT() Syntax

```
SELECT FORMAT(column_name,format) FROM table_name;
```

Your sql query look like:

```
SELECT ID, username, registration_date   FROM users
        WHERE DATEDIFF(registration_date, NOW()) % 7 = 0
```

or

```
 SELECT ID, username, registration_date   FROM users
                WHERE MOD(DATEDIFF(registration_date, NOW()), 7) = 0
```